# Can we call sql function in prepared statement?

Tags: oracle, function, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a oracle function. function name is TESTFUNCTION. The code i used is

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT dbo.TESTFUNCTION(?,?)") ;
```

and I set the parameters also.

```
ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
```

This code will produce the below exception

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Any Help!!

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the FROM keyword. Change to this:

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT dbo.TESTFUNCTION(?,?) FROM dual;") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to execute a SELECT statement, and you either missed or misplaced the FROM keyword. Try to check for the from keyword.

Check [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00923.php) for details.

Note: It would be preferrable to use [Callable Statement](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-statements.htm) instead of prepared statement in such cases.

You could use callable statement in this case as:

```
String SQL = "{call dbo.TESTFUNCTION(?,?)}";
   cstmt = con.prepareCall (SQL);
```

Comment: create or replace
FUNCTION TESTFUNCTION (PARAM1 IN VARCHAR2 , PARAM2 IN VARCHAR2) RETURN sys_refcursor IS referenceCursor sys_refcursor;

BEGIN
  OPEN REFERENCECURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM EXT_ADM_REGISTER WHERE USERNAME = PARAM1 AND DATEOFBIRTH = PARAM2;
  RETURN referencecursor;  
END;

Comment: here return type is cursor. am not using any cursor in my code. is this is the problem?

Comment: I dont understand why you are using select statement for this function. You can just execute it to get the desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

A [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) is useful for SQL queries and not for function call. For function calls and stored procedures, use [CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html).